# binding plsql (TYPE t_table_var IS ARRAY(1) OF tt_tabl_var) with C#

Tags: c#, plsql, database-connection

Dears,

I need some help here please.

I am trying to bind my TYPE t_table_var IS ARRAY(1) OF  tt_tabl_var --> used in plsql package
with C# API.

```
TYPE  
  tt_tabl_var     FORCE AS OBJECT
(
    aaaaaaaa1                    VARCHAR2(24 BYTE),
    aaaaaaaa2                    VARCHAR2(24 BYTE),
    aaaaaaaa3                    VARCHAR2(22 BYTE),
```

note: I am using Oracle.DataAccess to connect my database with C# and I would prefer to keep my solution as it is.

Best Regards,

am expecting to use any guaranteed ideas to connect my PLSQL with C# API.